# Regex to find all lines containing foo_bar or not foo

Tags: regex, grep

I'm stumped writing a regex to put into grep to match all lines which contain foo_bar and all other lines to don't contain foo_.* (Excepting foo_bar which should still match).

So given:

```
foo_bar Line 1
foo_baz Line 2
Line 3
foo_biz Line 4
```

I'd want Lines 1 and 3 returned.

Note I can't just match not foo_baz and not foo_biz as baz and biz can be many, many things. It needs to be foo_.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under OS X I executed the following command on your input :

```
$ grep -P -v '^foo_(?!bar)' test.txt 
foo_bar Line 1
Line 3
```

Please note that :

```
-P, --perl-regexp
       Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
-v, --invert-match
       Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

Comment: I came up with the same line.. you are 1min faster. :)

Comment: This is great - a minor modification to put a .* between ^ and foo and It works perfectly.

Comment: You're right. I based the answer on your example but you stated that it could be anywhere in the text. Using grep you could remove the `^` and not have to add `.*`

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine a postivie match and a negative match
So positive Match 1 for foo_bar

```
foo_bar
```

Then negative match 2 for all this is not containing foo_ using Stack overflow great explanation
[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

```
^((?!foo_.*).)*$
```

Combining both in an altnernative regexp

```
(foo_bar|^((?!foo_.*).)*$)
```

Now let's try::

```
    $ cat <<EOF | perl -ane ' /(foo_bar|^((?!foo_.*).)*$)/ && print $_'
    > foo_bar 1
    > fee_foo
    > foo bar
    > foo_buz RT
    > fo_foo 1 
    > fo_ foo_bar
    > EOF
```

gives

```
foo_bar 1
fee_foo
foo bar
fo_foo 1 
fo_ foo_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/foo_bar/p;/foo_/!p' input
```

this tells the sed not to print by default (`-n`) and print when either `foo_bar` matches or `foo_` does not match.